# Can I eliminate namespace declarations in this transformation output?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to dynamically generate an XML file using XMLT that takes another XML file as input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="data">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="books" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="books">
   <books>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="chapters" />
   </books>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapters">
  <chapter name="{@name}" source="{@source}"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="pages" />
  </chapter>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="pages" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
   <xi:include>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xi:include>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My desired output is below.

```
<chapter 
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude" name="chapter1">
    <xi:include>page1</xi:include>
    <xi:include>page2</xi:include>
    <xi:include>page3</xi:include>
</chapter>
```

Unfortunately, my code generates the output below.

```
<chapter 
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude" name="chapter1">
    <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">page1</xi:include>
    <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">page2</xi:include>
    <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">page3</xi:include>
</chapter>
```

Is there a way I could eliminate the actual URI for the namespace for I can have xi:include tages without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="data">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="books" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="books">
   <books>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="chapters" />
   </books>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapters">
  <chapter name="{@name}" source="{@source}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="pages" />
  </chapter>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="pages">
   <xi:include>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xi:include>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do note that your are using **two different namespace URIs**:

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude
```

and

```
http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude
```

If they were the same, the [namespace fixup process](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#namespace-fixup) would take care of that.

For this input:

```
<books>
    <chapters name="chapter1">
        <pages name="page1"/>
        <pages name="page2"/>
        <pages name="page3"/>
    </chapters>
</books>
```

This stylesheet (yours with amended typo):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="books" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="books">
        <books>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="chapters" />
        </books>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="chapters">
        <chapter name="{@name}" source="{@source}"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pages" />
        </chapter>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pages" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude">
        <xi:include>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xi:include>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<books>
    <chapter name="chapter1" source="" 
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XInclude">
        <xi:include>page1</xi:include>
        <xi:include>page2</xi:include>
        <xi:include>page3</xi:include>
    </chapter>
</books>
```